# Show carousel of image using vue3 carousel

Tags: nuxt.js

I am trying to display images using vue3 carousel

I am having problem, using vu3 carousel in Nuxt 3. I can't display the images. If i use slide with a range like in the example in vu3 carousel, it works fine, but when try to use image, it didn't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXILx.png)